# Save Huffman bitcode table to file

Tags: c#, compression, huffman-code

I have finished my Huffman compression/decompression algorithm. I use an string to check my input, like "foo bar" 7x8 = 56 gives me 10010110111011100 = 17 +- 35% from original size compressed back.

But now I want to save it as a file, can anyone explain me an approach how to do this.

If needed I can post the source of my application.

Comment: Of course you should provide us code that shows what you want to save

Comment: or you can just search by "byte array stream write to file"

Comment: Do you need to know how to save "10010110111011100" to a file?